# value is not able to be passed in useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Context.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useReducer,
  useState,
} from "react";
import { cartReducer } from "./Reducer";

const Cart = createContext();

const Context = ({ children }) => {
  const [products, getProduct] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/api/products/").then((response) => {
      getProduct(response.data);
    });
  }, []);
  console.log(products);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, {
    products: products,
    cart: [],
  });
  console.log(state);

  return <Cart.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>{children}</Cart.Provider>;
};

export default Context;

export const cartState = () => {
  return useContext(Cart);
};
```

I successfully called axios.get and console log the value of products and it has all the products in it, but when I try to pass it in useReducer and try to log the state it shows empty array.

Reducer.js

```
export const cartReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: We need to see how cartReducer looks like to answer this

Comment: In this case you dont need useState and useReducer, you just copying the state to the reducer - it doesnt make sense, just pick either of them and initial them.
For why you see an empty array, its because you are loggin stale state, you missing another render to see the updated state, force render and you will see it. I would suggest to read the docs again to understand what the usecases.

Answer (score 1):

```
 const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, {
    products: products,
    cart: [],
  });
```

useReducer only need products for initail the state it will be not updated just because you update products with useState;

And you are keeping the state in both useState and useReducer you should be using only one.

if you use useReducer then

action structure should {type,payload}

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((pervState,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case "setProducts":
            return {...prevState,products:action.payload};
        case "setCart":
            return {...prevState,cart:cart.payload};
        default:
            throw new Error(`unhandled action.type ${action.type}`)
        }
    },{
    products: products,
    cart: [],
  });
```